# Clearing session data once a dialogue (modal) window opens [No Repeat]

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, modal-dialog

I have already got this working by implementing the following on my modal JSP page:

1) On close, call `location.reload()` wrapped in to an `onclick()` event function.

2) On reloading the parent page, clear the session data.

I am trying to do this without reloading the parent page i.e. if I just click the close button on my modal dialog window, the session data is cleaned up.

Before anyone says this, I know that javascript is front-end and request/session stuff is back end. But I am interested to know if an AJAX call can make this happen or any framework that makes this possible. My objective is "Clear session, but don't reload the parent page"

P.S. I am not sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202944/modal-window-once-a-session-with-jquery) is applicable to me.

Kindest Regards,

Comment: Have you tried `session_destroy()` in an AJAX call? Seems like it would be pretty quick to test. Though the session information will still be available until a new page loads.

Comment: @Stef                      "until a new page loads" meaning the modal page or the parent page? All I am trying to do is close the modal page and then open it again, and get a fresh page without any errors/warnings on my form data. Isn't `session_destroy` going to destroy everything as I need to destroy some, not all session variables.

Comment: I can't say for sure without testing it, but the session data should be available on the parent page until it reloads. The modal page is a different story. If you're reloading it then it should be fine. If you need to destroy only some of the session data though, I'd recommend the cookie approach. Anything with PHP and page reloads seems hacky to me, but I don't know how your application is structured so that's really up to you.